# Clipboard ASP.NET C# : Получение скопированной информации из буфера обмена

Tags: c#, clipboard, buffer

В моей задаче нужно, чтобы по нажатию кнопки содержимое буфера было записано в `TextBox`. Буфер полон, но при попытке получить информацию я получаю `System.NullReferenceException`. Проверка функцией `Clipboard.ContainsText()` тоже говорит о том, что буфер обмена пуст (`NO_BUFFER_DATA`).

Мой код:

```
        string GetBufferText()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.IDataObject iData = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            if (iData.GetDataPresent(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Text))
            {
                return iData.GetData(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Text).ToString();
            }
            return "CANNOT_GET_DATA";
        }
        protected void btnBordFromBuff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Добавление текста в буфер (Проходит успешно)
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => Clipboard.SetText(tbLink.Text));
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
            //Вытягивание текста из буфера
            if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
            {
                tbMinId.Text = GetBufferText();
                tbMaxId.Text = GetBufferText();
            }
            else
            {
                tbMinId.Text = "NO_BUFFER_DATA";
                tbMaxId.Text = "NO_BUFFER_DATA";
            }
        }
```

Как исправить код так, чтобы `Clipboard` обнаружил текст, хранящийся в буфере обмена?

Использование `Clipboard.SetText(tbLink.Text)` без потока дает ошибку `System.Threading.ThreadStateException`

Comment: 1. Почему стоит метка [asp net-mvc]? 2. Зачем используете `Thread`? 3. Почему в WPF проекте используется WinForms?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ага, тоже взрыв мозга и когнитивный диссонанс.

Comment: В какой строке  `я получаю System.NullReferenceException`? А то у вас может Clipboard == null.

Comment: Конкретно на ваш вопрос ответ таков: вы запускаете поток, но не дожидаетесь его завершения и сразу проверяете clipboard. Он пуст, т. к. код в потоке ещё не отработал.

Comment: Если вам что-то непонятно - спросите под ответом, не плодите [дубликаты вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1188545/213987).

Comment: Исправил некорректные метки.

Comment: А какой смысл в буфере обмена, у WEB проекта, который рассчитан быть сервером? Что вы там копировать-то собрались?

Answer (score 1):

Как то вы все слишком усложнили и замешали в кучу. Тест в проекте WPF.NET Framework 4.7.2, обработчик вашей кнопки. Потоки вам точно не нужны(наверное вы тестировали в консоли,а там с вас требовали поток STA), если вы используете WPF, заче тянуть Clipboard из WinForm

```
private void btnBordFromBuff_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Clipboard.SetText(tbLink.Text);

    if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
    {
        tbMinId.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
    }
}
```